# How can I change this once clicked submit button it "Post" and redirect to thank you page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How can I change this once clicked submit button it "Post" and redirect to thank you page? I'm new to this and I'm stock and need your help. Thank you.

```
<div class="row" data-ar-id="knPGryb10X">
        
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto" data-ar-id="2a8BIf57NA">
          
        <form method="POST" action="https://storage/projects/1/ohPw14Bn7yEqk8K3BHmUfj4LDUw7PwlweOou/default-form-handler" class="" data-ar-id="72Xz7Iimkn">
    <div class="control-group" data-ar-id="46igvgmRN2">
      <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2" data-ar-id="CNJEStnEZk">
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" data-ar-id="RBHvtUd4UV">
      <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2" data-ar-id="2JsYZhLtPe">
        <label data-ar-id="p3n77pazVO">Email Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." data-ar-id="bKETslityp">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" data-ar-id="3E9itexHyL">
      
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" data-ar-id="r3Tt4ulNfM">
      <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2" data-ar-id="llWK5VUTQp">
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" data-ar-id="gg7EinsWzs"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" type="submit" data-ar-id="GmTydIJXpg">Send</button></div>
  </form></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The form's `action` is supposed to be the URL of the PHP script handling the form data. In this script, simply output whatever you like and the browser will display it. It works just like a link.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can change action attribute of you form tag. This will post the content of the to the specified URL and get the content of the targeted page.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Replace form tag on your exemple by:
`<form method="POST" action="https://mydomain.ext/mypage" class="" data-ar-id="72Xz7Iimkn">`

If you just want navigate to another page without send data you can use a link:
`<a href="https://mydomain.ext/mypage">Go to my page</a>`